# Ubuntu 18.04 Pulseaudio, split front panel jack into separate sink from back panel front jack

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

My setup is that I have a pair of speakers running of the front panel headphone jack and my 5.1 headphones are plugged into the back panel jacks (front, rear, sub & center) and the motherboard has the Realtek ALC892 chip.

In Windows 10 I toggled an option in the Realtek driver to split the outputs into individual outputs and therefor I can run separate audio streams to my headset and speakers.

I would like to have this same setup in ubuntu 18.04 as well.

So far I have opened **alsamixer** and turned of auto-mute which gives me the same sound output on both the speakers and my headphones. The speakers show up under the 'Headphone' channel in alsamixer and my headset is currently only running on the 'front' channel. And I can then mute one of them to only have sound-output on the other.

Then I found that you can remap sinks in pulseaudio and there were a lot of threads where they suggest using the remap-sink module, but the examples I found were mostly for remapping stuff plugged into the backpanel such as the following line:

```
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=headphones 
sink_properties="device.description='Speakers'" 
remix=no 
master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo 
channels=2 
master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right 
channel_map=front-left,front-right
```

Which I understand to create a sink called "Speakers" where the front channel output will be mapped to go out through the rear channel of the backpanel.

Now my question is what name I should put instead of 'rear-left' and 'rear-right' if I want it to map to my frontpanel jack(The one that shows up as 'headphone' in *alsamixer*)?
Or if this is the completely wrong route to take for archiving this.

Comment: Hello. Did you ever achieve this? I've installed JACK but have a hard time grasping the way it works.